# Running a script of any language in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, shell, scripting

I can execute shell command in Ruby using:

```
def run(code)
    %x[ #{code} ]
end
```

I can also evaluate Ruby script in Ruby using:

```
def run(code)
    eval(code)
end
```

Is there a way to blindly execute/evaluate `code` as a shell script, regardless of the language? I'm thinking of including `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` at the beginning of `code`, but not sure how to form the string and invoke it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but not sure how to form the string and invoke it.

You're on the right track with `#!/bin/bash` and `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` which point to the binaries used to interpret the code, but I'm not sure if you can pass in the code as a string - you might need to save the code to a temporary file first, and then run it:

```
require 'tempfile'

code = "#!/bin/bash\necho 'hello world'"
interpreter = code.match(/#!(.*)/)[1]

file = Tempfile.new('foo')
file.write(code)
file.close
%x(#{interpreter} #{file.path})  # prints "hello world"
```

Of course you could also create the temp file, mark it as executable (chmod), and just run it directly. Then your last step wouldn't need the interpreter specified:

```
%x(#{file.path})  # prints "hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the shell command `ruby -e`.

```
%x["ruby -e " + code]
```